Null results in a fastapi machine learning script
i'm working on a fastAPI simple machine learning script. I've already trained succesfully the pipeline, and it works as intended. But now i'm trying to use fastAPI and uvicorn in order to deploy it. I have no clue why it return always a null value as results. It's a binary classification. Some datas go in, and a 1 or 0 should go out. Right now i did this:
from pydantic import BaseModel
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    import pandas as pd
    import joblib
    
    import uvicorn
    
    
    # instance
    app = FastAPI()
    
    
    # data model
    class DataModel(BaseModel):
        id: str
        radius_mean: float
        ...
        # all other features, except for target variable that has to be predicted

class ItemOut(BaseModel):
    id: str
    diagnosis: int


def load_weights():
    model = joblib.load("models/RF/RF_weights_v1.0.pkl")
    return model


def predict(data):
    model = load_weights()
    preprocessing = model.named_steps["preprocessing"]
    transformed_data = preprocessing.transform(data)
    classifier = model.named_steps["classifier"]
    predicted_values = classifier.predict(transformed_data)
    return predicted_values


@app.post("/predict", response_model=ItemOut)
async def predict(dataModel: DataModel):
    data = pd.DataFrame([dataModel.dict()])
    predictions = predict(data)
    return {"id": "id", "diagnosis": predictions}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.1", port=8000)

Now, i have no idea if the weights of the model are loaded correctly. On top of that, the result of the predict should be an array of 1 dimension (in this case only one value) with the 0 or 1 based on the calssification result.
But a null value is returned instead.
The model i'm using is a "SVC" (i've a second one done with random forest, nothing too fancy).
What i'm doing wrong?
And again, i have no idea if it's the best approach or for example, the best practice should be to load a json with those valuesm or load a json file with multiple values.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

If diagnosis should be an array of 1 dimension - use diagnosis: list[int] at least, but problem I assume in classifier.predict(transformed_data)
Could you share more code what this methods do, and what you have in pkl ?
